# Java: I'm trying to display a date with methods from a class i made called Date but when i try to run it into another class the numbers won't display

Tags: java, constructor, getmethod

i need help with my homework. It's about making your own class and then using the methods you made inside that class into another class to perform a certain task.I've made two classes one being Date with my constructor and all my methods for the class and one class called DateTest to display my result. In my case i want my program to display a text with the initial date i hard coded in there and then display a second line of text that will show a new date. My problem is that when i run the program it only diplays the text where it shows the initialized date and the new date but it doesn't print the acutal digits. I think it might have to do something with my get methods but im not sure. I'm also new to this website so please bare any mistakes i've mad to make this post very ugly looking.

**CODE FROM CLASS DATE**

```
public class Date {

//instance variables
private int month;
private int day;
private int year;

//constructor
public Date( int month, int day, int year){
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;
}

    //set methods
    public void setMonth (int month){
        this.month = month;
    }

    public void setDay(int day){
        this.day = day;
    }

    public void setYear(int year){
        this.year = year;
    }

    //get methods
    public int getMonth(){
        return month;
    }

    public int getDay(){
        return day;
    }

    public int getYear(){
        return year;
    }

    //Display mehtod
    public String displayDate(){
        return "Date with new values is: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;
    }

    }//end of coding
```

**CODE FROM DATETEST**

```
public class DateTest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
     Date date1 = new Date( 7, 4, 2004 );// create new date object

      System.out.println( "The initial date is: ");//display initial value
      date1.getMonth();
      date1.getDay();
      date1.getYear();
      date1.displayDate();

      // change date values
      date1.setMonth( 11 );
      date1.setDay( 1 );
      date1.setYear( 2003 );

      System.out.println( "Date with new values is: " );
      date1.displayDate();

      System.out.println();          // output a newline

}

}//end class DateTest
```

**WHAT HAPPENS WHEN I RUN MY PROGRAM**

The initial date is: 
Date with new values is: 
(The numbers for the date aren't appearing)

Answer (score 1):

`Return` just returns a value from a method, it does not print it. You'll need to use the method or something like `System.out`
for example

```
public int getMonth(){
    return month; //not print 
}
```

a method of this style should print something like

```
System.out.println(date1.getMonth()); // print the return value obtained from the method
```

if you have a method like this

```
public int getMonth(){
    System.out.println(month); //Yes, print 
}
```

there if you can call it from your main class and the value is printed

```
date1.getMonth();
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are new to Java, Now the thing about `System.out.println()` is that you need something which is not empty to be inside the brackets of

`println(*SOME VALUE SHOULD GO HERE*)`

Now back to you Q, `date1.displayDate();` is returning a string that carries the date in a cute mannar but this returned value is not used anywhere so you really can't print it.

Now if you wanna print the string

> Date with new values is: " + month + "/" + day + "/" + year;

do something like this,

```
String dateValue=date1.getDate();
System.out.println(dateValue);
```

This code can be further crunched into something like this,

```
System.out.println(date1.getDate());
```

hope this explains the question , and if this works dont forget to accept my answer, cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You are not printing the statment .

```
  date1.displayDate();
```

The above statement should be inside

### System.out.println(date1.displayDate());